# Freeing struct with pointer and non-pointer variables

Tags: c, memory, struct

I'm trying to implement linked-lists with c struct, I use malloc to allocate a new node then allocate space for `value`, so I've been thinking how to free the structure once I'm done with them, my structure looks like this:

```
typedef struct llist {
     char *value;
     int line;
     struct llist *next;
} List;
```

I have a function that walks through the struct and free its members like this:

```
free(s->value);
free(s);
```

My question is, does that also free the `int line`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

The `int line` is part of the structure, and so gets freed when you free the structure.  The same is true of the `char *value`.  However, this does not free the memory which `value` points at, which is why you need to call `free` separately for that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does. When you allocated memory for s it allocated memory for these three:

pointer to a char (value)
integer (line)
pointer to a struct llist (next)

When you freed s, all that storage went away (which includes memory for line).